# How can I make a for loop to read multiple txt files?

Tags: matlab

First of all, thank you so much. So, the problem is:
I have a function that Matlab has created by using the Import Data Tool. The function is called 'importkeff'. The problem is that I have a lot of txt files with the same structure and I haven´t been able to create a for loop to execute the function and save the values in different vectors.
I have tried this but I know is wrong.
The txt files are named like this: 0000.V5W19.T17, 0001.V5W19.T17, 0002... and so until 0069.

```
for i=01:69
00ikeff19 = importkeff('00i.V5W19.T17')
end
```

Any ideas on how can I create a for loop to do it?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```matlab
keff = cell(69, 1);
for i=1:69
  keff{i} = importkeff(sprintf("%04d", i) + ".V5W19.T17");
end
```

Comment: WOW! Now it looks easy :) Thank u so much